# What is an End Plate?

Tags: electrical

I've been researching electrical stuffs in the internet with unimpressive results. I'm a complete noob in electrical stuffs so please be patient with me.

What is an End Plate and what is a terminal block stopper and what are the differences?

Where do I learn stuffs like these are there sort of books about these? I'm a bit confused with different terminologies such as angle connectors, din rails, T, LR, LL conduit, etc.

Comment: Vote as off topic

Comment: The is not at all off topic @Kris. They are asking for clarification of electrical terminology.

Comment: @Corbee, what is your location? Some of these terms are unfamiliar to me, or at least too general, like "end plate". That could be something in any trade.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey I found it here http://uk.farnell.com/phoenix-contact/3047028/terminal-block-end-plate-2-5-10mm/dp/8333300

Comment: @Corbee, what is your goal?  This site provides DIY help answers to questions that involve home improvement.  You did not provide enough information.  Sounds more like homework.

Comment: @Corbee, thank you. The UK has some very different terms than the US (where I am).

Comment: @SpeedyPetey I'm interested in learning handyman stuffs so I went researching about the parts I found in retail stores. My goal right now is to get a general idea of those electrical stuffs.

Comment: @Corbee what you linked is a industrial communication network part... no where near the realm of handyman.

Answer (score 3):

There are good introduction-to-house-wiring books available. Home centers often have these, or cover the basics in a chapter of their general home maintenance books. Your local public library is likely to have much more detailed books, or can order them for you via inter-library loan.

For the questions you're asking, it sounds like reading through one of those would be an excellent investment of your time and money.  Asking here's more useful when something needs clarification or you have a question that's more in the how-to range.